# Send One Signal push notification with Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, ionic-framework, guzzle, onesignal

I created a mobile application with Ionic 3 and I would like send notification in Symfony 3 via One Signal.

I read the documentation of One Signal and this documentation: https://github.com/norkunas/onesignal-php-api/blob/master/docs/setup-guzzle5.md

I created a service in Symfony, but I'm blocked, I do not know what to put in

```
$guzzle = new GuzzleClient([
                            // ..config
                           ]);
```

My service :

```
<?php

namespace SGBundle\Service\OneSignal;

use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
use Http\Adapter\Guzzle5\Client as GuzzleAdapter;
use Http\Client\Common\HttpMethodsClient as HttpClient;
use Http\Message\MessageFactory\GuzzleMessageFactory;
use OneSignal\Config;
use OneSignal\Devices;
use OneSignal\OneSignal;
use SGBundle\Controller\BaseController;

/**
 * Class OneSignalService
 *
 * @package SGBundle\Service\OneSignal
 */
class OneSignalService extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function sendMessage()
    {
        $config = new Config();
        $config->setApplicationId('xxx');
        $config->setApplicationAuthKey('xx');
        $config->setUserAuthKey('xxx');

        $guzzle = new GuzzleClient([
                                       // ..config
                                   ]);

        $client = new HttpClient(new GuzzleAdapter($guzzle), new GuzzleMessageFactory());
        $api = new OneSignal($config, $client);

    }
```

And where I define the body of my notification (title and message for example) ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: No one to help me ? :/